# how to create a sparsematrix from DataFrame in a specific format

Tags: python, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I am working with python 3.5 with a DataFrame with columns = ['users_id', 'item_id', 'rating', 'timestamp', 'title'] and i am using 
         `model = LightFM(loss='warp')`  for recommender model

so for the trainning i need a sparseMatrix in a specific format => (users_id, item_id) rating

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyl5c.png)

but i never succeeded  when i use this`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(data['users_id'])`. It gives me something like this :

(0,0) 5

(0,1) 5

(0,2) 4

(0,3) 5

How should i procced ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create a sparse matrix to after use it in your LightFM model, I think you should use the [Dataset](http://lyst.github.io/lightfm/docs/lightfm.data.html) object which is provided by the library. For example, if I call your DataFrame df :

```
from lightfm.data import Dataset

data = Dataset()
data.fit(df.users_id.unique(), df.item_id.unique())
interactions_matrix, weights_matrix = data.build_interactions([tuple(i) for i in df.drop(['timestamp', 'title'], axis = 1).values])
```

The fit method is use to map your users_id and items_id to an inner id and the build_interactions method create two sparse matrix, one binary with only the interactions between users and items and an other one with the weights (i.e. ratings), it takes an iterable of (user_id, item_id) or (user_id, item_id, weight) as parameter.

Then you can use these two matrices created with build_interactions to fit your model in LightFM.

```
from lightfm import LightFM

model = LightFM(loss='warp')
model.fit(interactions_matrix, sample_weight = weights_matrix)
```

You can find more information in the LightFM [documentation](http://lyst.github.io/lightfm/docs/index.html), you can see for example the section about [Building Datasets](http://lyst.github.io/lightfm/docs/examples/dataset.html) or the [Quickstart](http://lyst.github.io/lightfm/docs/quickstart.html).

Comment: great help! I think you should show `df` though. To see exactly what variables you are keeping when you do the drop. Thanks!